# O mail do php envia os emails em segundo plano?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde envio email para diversos usuarios, aonde ele envia o email e altera a coluna SEND no bando de dados para true com um intervalo de 10 segundo
entre cada envio. Então tentei simular uma queda de energia, e minha percepção seria. "Bom faltou energia entao ele vai parar de enviar os emails e tambem não vai alterar a coluna no mysql". Porem o que percebi e que mesmo com o navegador fechado ele ainda continuava realizando o loop, enviando o email e atualizando a coluna no mysql, então claramente pense, isso é otimo, e me veio a curiosidade, o php e mysql no caso continuam a trabalhar em segundo plano, ou seja com todo o sistema fechado? Apenas uma observação, sou recem nascido no PHP

Segue o codigo:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $nameUser = $value['userName'];
    $email = $value['userEmail'];
    $headers = "From:  $nameD  $addressee \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $nameD  $addressee \r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $html = str_replace("true", "false", $bodyEmail);
    mail($email, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subjects) . '?=', str_replace("nomedousuario", "$nameUser", $html), $headers);
    $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET send = 'true', selectionType = 'noSelect'   WHERE userEmail = '$email'");
    $update->execute();
    sleep(10);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ele continuou executando mesmo após o navegador ser fechado, pois você já tinha feito a requisição e o que executa o o PHP é o servidor apache. Se você quiser interromper o envio é só desligar o servidor apache que o PHP para de ser executado.

Comment: Errado não está, não entendi porque tanto negativo...

Comment: muito menos eu...